# Right way to use CUDA based functions in a ROS context

Tags: c++, cuda, ros

I am working on a ROS-based pipeline whose main function is to subscribe to image topics and execute functions such as feature detection, matching etc continuously. To make this pipeline faster, I am trying to use CUDA based detection and matching modules as part of my package. In the context of this question, I am assuming a simple pipeline where I subscribe to an image topic, and in the subscriber callback which is called every time an image is available, two member functions of different classes are called: one for detection, another to match, each containing its own CUDA kernel. Somewhat similar to executing those two functions in a loop.

The first function takes the image data and computes feature keypoints and descriptors, returning them to the host. I then copy these descriptors back into the GPU memory and I need to match them with another set of descriptors which belong to a reference image.

For example, this is how the standalone matching function looks like:

```
// Detection module returns a struct featureData, containing keypoints and descriptors 
// in featureData.kps and featureData.desc

uint64_t* d_desc;
cudaMalloc(&d_desc, 64 * featureData.kps.size());
cudaMemcpy(d_desc, &featureData., 64 * (featureData.kps.size()), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudaDeviceSetCacheConfig(cudaFuncCachePreferL1);
cudaDeviceSetSharedMemConfig(cudaSharedMemBankSizeEightByte);

// Create texture object for descriptors

struct cudaResourceDesc resDesc;
memset(&resDesc, 0, sizeof(resDesc));
resDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypeLinear;
resDesc.res.linear.devPtr = d_desc;
resDesc.res.linear.desc.f = cudaChannelFormatKindUnsigned;
resDesc.res.linear.desc.x = 32;
resDesc.res.linear.desc.y = 32;
resDesc.res.linear.sizeInBytes = 64 * featureData.kps.size();

struct cudaTextureDesc texDesc;
memset(&texDesc, 0, sizeof(texDesc));
texDesc.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeBorder;
texDesc.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeBorder;
texDesc.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;
texDesc.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;
texDesc.normalizedCoords = 0;
cudaTextureObject_t tex_q = 0;
cudaCreateTextureObject(&tex_q, &resDesc, &texDesc, nullptr);

// Allocate space for match results
int* d_matches;
cudaMalloc(&d_matches, 4 * featureData.kps.size());

// Launch the matching kernel
CUDAmatch(d_descRef, static_cast<int>(refData.kps.size()), tex_q, static_cast<int>(featureData.kps.size()), d_matches, threshold);

// d_descRef is memory pointed to by a uint64_t* for the reference descriptors.
```

In this context, I have a few questions, as it is my first foray into GPU-based development.

1. The descriptors etc. are copied into the device memory when it is time to perform the matching, and the results are copied back afterwards. Should I free the device memory pointers for these after performing matching every time and reallocate (`cudaMalloc()`) in the next callback? The length of the descriptors will be changing based on the number of features detected. Or is there a more efficient way to allocate memory only once and reuse it?
2. The detection and matching functions also make use of objects such as `cudaResourceDesc` and `cudaTextureDesc`, which will go out of scope at the end of every execution and thus should be destroyed. Should I handle them in any other specific way?
3. I assume I need `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after executing each of these two functions. Am I correct?
4. Can I safely leave the "reference" descriptors in GPU memory and only update them when I need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I free the device memory pointers for these after performing matching every time and reallocate (cudaMalloc()) in the next callback?

Probably not.  This would appear to be unnecessary and time-consuming.

> Or is there a more efficient way to allocate memory only once and reuse it?

Probably.  For example, you could determine the maximum size possibly needed, allocate for that, then pass a pointer to it into your event processing loop, and reuse the allocation.

> The detection and matching functions also make use of objects such as cudaResourceDesc and cudaTextureDesc, which will go out of scope at the end of every execution and thus should be destroyed. Should I handle them in any other specific way?

Similarly, you could create them at a higher scope, and pass references to them into your event processing system.  However, I think that the main time consumers here will be the data copy to populate the texture, and the binding of the texture.  These would have to be repeated anyway (presumably).  But if you have an underlying allocation for the backing store for the texture object, then you probably would not need to reallocate for that, see previous comments.

> I assume I need cudaDeviceSynchronize() after executing each of these two functions. Am I correct?

It's not obvious to me that it is needed.  You haven't shown a complete example, but if, at the end of your functions, there is a copy of data from device to host, that will probably suffice. `cudaMemcpy` is a blocking function.  If you are operating in a physically/logically unified memory situation such as TX1/TX2, then yes, you may need a sync point to ensure that data is valid before you consume it in host code.

> Can I safely leave the "reference" descriptors in GPU memory and only update them when I need to?

I don't know why not.  An allocation created by `cudaMalloc` does not "go out of scope" until either application termination, or explicitly free'd with `cudaFree`.  If you copy data to such an allocation, it should remain there, unchanged, for the duration of your application, unless you overwrite it somehow (or free the underlying allocation).